# hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Read permission

Tags: jenkins

I'm running jenkins and getting this error

> hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Read
>   permission

I tried many times, deleted cookies and all.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling security is **not** the solution. It's probably there for a reason. Try "login" instead

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://yourserver/jenkins/ login --username usr --password qwerty
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue I faced but with GitHub OAuth plugin,my problem and solution explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/789420/jenkins-login-using-github-authentication-failed-being-administrator/789421#789421)

Errors 
 hudson.security.AccessDeniedException2: anonymous is missing the Overall/Administer permission at hudson.security.ACL.checkPermission(ACL.java:57)

org.kohsuke.github.HttpException: Server returned HTTP response code: -1, message: 'null' for URL: https://ghe.acme.com/api/v3/user

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security

I am able to run 
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://server get-job myjob > myjob.xml

works for me using abouv url

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the above link, use these simple and clear steps

I think some of the answers in here were partial. This is how I resolved it:

Step Jenkins 
/etc/init.d/jenkins stop 
sudo vi /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml (Please copy the complete text somewhere first, so that later you don't run in other problems)

2.A. change useSecurity element's value to false 
false

2.B. Remove authorizationStrategy block

Start Jenkins again: 
/etc/init.d/jenkins start

Access Jenkins through URL and reconfigure security again.